# What is the point in setting something equal to itself?

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters, module-pattern

I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20888418/1022697) into which someone passed `window.Module = window.Module || {}` into a function.

For example:

```
(function(module){
    // do something with module
})(window.Module = window.Module || {});
```

I understand that if `window.Module` is undefined (or false for that matter) then `{}` would be passed in, but what is the point in setting `window.Module` equal to itself?

---

For people posting answers:

I read the code as:

```
if(!(window.Module = window.Module)) {
     // pass {} into function
}
else {
     // pass window.Module = window.Module into function 
     // (which makes NO sense to me)
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's being used like that just because of the conditionality? If false, give empty object. Shorter than an if statement?

Comment: yes, by setting it to itself, you are basically doing "nothing" if it exists, if not, set to empty object. just shorthand if

Comment: You may find this question helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-this-construct-x-x-y-mean

Comment: `if( !( 'Module' in window ) ) window.Module = {};` is how I would do it, then there is no self assignment. However in the long run of things, this isn't going to matter really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That bit does two things:

1. The `window.Module || {}` bit uses [JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) to evaluate to either `window.Module` (if it's truthy) or `{}` (if `window.Module` is falsey). `||` evalutes to its first non-falsey operand. Then the result of that is assigned to `window.Module`. The result is that *if* `window.Module` was falsey (probably `undefined`), it gets `{}` assigned to it; if it wasn't falsey (it probably already refers to an object), in theory it gets reassigned to itself although in practice engines are probably smart enough not to bother with the dead store.
2. Then it passes the result of the assignment (the value [now] in `window.Module`) into the function.

So the end result is that `window.Module` is set to a new blank object if it wasn't set before, and regardless of whether it was set before, whatever object is (now) in `window.Module` is passed into the function.

Answer (score 1):

This confusion is why I'm not a fan of the short-circuit expression over a simple `if`.

Expressed using a conventional structure:

```
if (!window.Module)
{
    window.Module = {};
}
else
{
    // this is a no-op, and the whole else clause could be removed.
    window.Module = window.Module;
}
```

You can't use this structure in an expression, but it is more readable.

The main reason it's assigning `window.Module` is to be sure it's assigned. You could simply pass `window.Module || {}`, but that would leave it uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(module){
    // do something with module
})(window.Module = window.Module || {});
```

This code first makes sure that a global `Module` object is set, and then passes it into the function. If you left out the assignment:

```
(function(module){
    // do something with module
})(window.Module || {});
```

then `Module` would not be set (if it didn't exist at that point). Of course, `module` can be used to access the object, but some code inside the function may require `Module`.

---

A better pattern could be:

```
// global code
if (!iwindow.Module) window.Module = {};

(function () {
  // use Module
}());
```

Comment: Well in your last part, I would still pass `Module` into the function anyway, no? Isn't that always a good pattern?

Comment: @qwertynl I don't think so. For the sake of code clarity, `Module` should just be accessed as a global variable.